# Проблема с синтаксисом if

Tags: java, android, if

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в этой конструкции в скобках, после if только имя переменной, и, что в таком случае, происходит в коде?

```
if (mAnswerIsTrue) {                       
    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.true_button);    
}
else {                           
    mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.false_button);      
}
```

Comment: запись `if(m)` аналогична `if(m == true)`. Запись `if(!m)`, кстати, аналогична `if(m == false)`

Comment: @Miron, благодарю)

Comment: @Miron оформите свой комментарий как ответ, чтобы его можно было принять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блок после `if(выражение)` выполняется в том случае, если `выражение == true`. Если же `выражение != true`, т.е. `выражение == false`, то выполнится блок `else`. Запись же `if(выражение == true)` аналогична записи `if(выражение)`. Это происходит потому, что если `выражение == true`, то `if(выражение == true)` при компиляции превратится в `if(true == true)`, что аналогично `if(true)` - истина равна истине. Если взять `выражение == false`, то будет соответственно `if(false == true)`, что аналогично `if(false)` - ложь не равна истине.